# MVC .net core 3.1 trying to refresh view component using ajax/javascript, keep getting 500 Internal Sever Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When a user clicks a drop down item I want to refresh a view component depending on what the user chose in the drop down.  I have tried different ways to get the component to render but each one has resulted in a 500 error.  I know that my ajax and scripts calls are making it to my controller because of debug and once the controller returns, I get the 500 error

Here is the cshtml snippet of view comp:

```
<div id="component" class="panel-body">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("tk", new Timecard() { TimeCardType = Model.Flsa })
</div>
```

Here is the Controller code I am trying to call:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult RefreshView(string flsa)
{
    if (flsa == "N")
        return NonExempt(flsa);
    else
        return Exempt(flsa);
}

public IActionResult NonExempt(string flsa)
{
    return ViewComponent("_NonExempt", new Timecard() { TimeCardType = flsa });
}

public IActionResult Exempt(string flsa)
{
    return ViewComponent("Exempt", new Timecard() { TimeCardType = flsa });
}
```

And here are a couple of attempts in js/ajax to try and refresh it:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'RefreshView',
    data: { flsa: 'N' },
    method: "GET"
}).done(function (res) {
    $('#component').html(res);
});
```

and:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#component').load('RefreshView', {
        flsa: result.flsa
    });
});
```

And here is the error:

> jquery.js:9600 GET http://localhost:61440/TimeKeeper/RefreshView?flsa=N 500 (Internal Server Error)

Like I said, both of the above js snippets hit my controller fine.

screenshot oferror
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A979W.png)

Comment: Does your cosole throw any error? Have you tried turning on the Common Runtime Exceptions check on the Exception Settings panel? That may help to determinate what the actual error is.

Comment: It is worth adding an error handler to the Ajax call and looking at that. If you put a stop on the server action and it isn't hit then your routing isn't working. Try making the call in a browser URL - it should work as its a GET - RefresView?flsa=N (prefixing with the rest of your path, of course)

Comment: You're using the ViewComponent in a weird way. Can you show us your ViewComponent classes? It looks like you have 3 ViewComponent classes: tk, _NonExempt, and Exempt? Sometimes you might be able to achieve the same result without over engineering it. Have you tried just putting the dropdown change as query string?

Comment: And 1 error I immediately see is how you invoke the view component _NonExempt from your controller. It should be just NonExempt right? Is that where it throw the exception?

Comment: @DavidLiang no, it should have a an underscore in front, i see that my Exempt does not and that is a typo.  These are partial views/components so I named them with the preceding underscore.  I do have a seperate viewcomponent class that the razor code uses to render the initial component called tk.  But I cant call that class in my ajax code for some reason.

Comment: @EricMatsui: ViewComponent and PartialView are 2 different things, although they're similar. I think `ViewComponent()` takes the name of the view component as the first parameter, not the view/partial your view component is going to return. That's why I said you're using ViewComponent in a weird way. And please show us the details of that 500 Internal Server Error - just set a breakpoint in your program and copy the text when it breaks by the exception.

Comment: @DavidLiang i added a screenshot of the error in my original post

Comment: @EricMatsui: No, the actual server exception details.... Like when you set a break point and hit F5 to run the debug mode, run your program until it throws the exception. It should give you the error details, stack trace, etc...

Comment: @DavidLiang with your asking questions it lead me down a path where I fixed it.  You were right, I wasnt getting that ViewComponent was being used incorrectly, in my original case as you saw, my return ViewComponent was pointing to my actual component views, and not the "View Component" class that renders the components ("tk"), once I changed it to point to tk it works.  Thanks for the help